# how to customize sent emails in djoser?

Tags: django, djoser

I build React&Django project and use Djoser for registration and auth. I want to customize sent email content on Gmail. Where should I change it?

Answer (score 3):

In your django directory create an app or in existing app <my_app>
create a file

- **email.py**

then in <my_app> directory create template folder like:

- **templates/<my_app>/**

within the directory <my_app> create two html files:

- ActivateEmail.html
- ConfirmationEmail.html

Then in **ActivationEmail.html** add this code below:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% block subject %}
{% blocktrans %}Account activation on {{ site_name }}{% endblocktrans %}
{% endblock subject %}

{% block text_body %}
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you need to finish activation process on {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page to activate account:" %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/{{ url|safe }}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}
{% endblock text_body %}

{% block html_body %}
<p>{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you need to finish activation process on {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<p>{% trans "Please go to the following page to activate account:" %}</p>
<p><a href="{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/{{ url|safe }}">{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/{{ url|safe }}</a></p>

<p>{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}</p>

<p>{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}</p>

{% endblock html_body %}
```

And in your **ConfirmationEmail.html** add this code:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% block subject %}
{% blocktrans %}{{ site_name }} - Your account has been successfully created and activated!{% endblocktrans %}
{% endblock %}

{% block text_body %}
{% trans "Your account has been created and is ready to use!" %}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}
{% endblock text_body %}

{% block html_body %}
<p>{% trans "Your account has been created and is ready to use!" %}</p>

<p>{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}</p>

<p>{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}</p>
{% endblock html_body %}
```

Then **email.py** within your app <my_app> add this code below:

```py
from djoser import email
from djoser import utils
from djoser.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator


class ActivationEmail(email.ActivationEmail):
    template_name = '<my_app>/ActivationEmail.html'

    def get_context_data(self):
        # ActivationEmail can be deleted
        context = super().get_context_data()

        user = context.get("user")
        context["uid"] = utils.encode_uid(user.pk)
        context["token"] = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
        context["url"] = settings.ACTIVATION_URL.format(**context)
        return context


class ConfirmationEmail(email.ConfirmationEmail):
    template_name = '<my_app>/ConfirmationEmail.html'
```

then **EDIT**

- **ActivationEmail.html**
- **ConfirmationEmail.html**

however you **LIKE**.

Then the last step is to add The classes in email.py to replace the default templates
in activation/confirmation email.
The defaults are as in docs: [djoser docs](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#email)
Then in Djoser settings in settings.py file:

```py
DJOSER = {
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'HIDE_USERS': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user': 'myapp.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_create': 'myapp.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'myapp.serializers.UserSerializer',
    },
    (...)

}
```

Add this:

```py
DJOSER = {
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'HIDE_USERS': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user': 'myapp.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_create': 'myapp.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'myapp.serializers.UserSerializer',
    },
    'EMAIL': {
        'activation': 'myapp.email.ActivationEmail',
        'confirmation': 'myapp.email.ConfirmationEmail',
    },
    (...)
}
```

Then send Email activation instead of sending default template for user in his/her email, it'll send the ActivationEmail.html template for them

Note that the Djoser uses the [django-template-mail](https://django-templated-mail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_usage.html) for its activation email template.